# LInear regression model over different combinations of columns

Tags: r

I have some data which looks like:

```
         date Moratalaz Cuatro_Caminos Barrio_de_Pilar Vallecas
1  2010-01-01        35             19              23       21
2  2010-01-02        62             40              40       44
3  2010-01-03        76             65              53       55
4  2010-01-04        69             64              52       56
5  2010-01-05        67             52              40       54
6  2010-01-06        48             33              29       37
7  2010-01-07        37             50              28       28
8  2010-01-08        39             37              19       26
9  2010-01-09        47             33              31       33
10 2010-01-10        66             51              41       47
```

I can run a linear regression model over individual columns using:

```
  lm(data$Moratalaz ~ data$Cuatro_Caminos)
```

However, I would like to run the regression model over every combination of columns (excluding the date column)

I tried something like the following but was not able to get it working:

```
formula_list <- list(as.formula('data$Moratalaz ~ data$Barrio_de_Pilar'),
                   as.formula('data$Barrio_de_Pilar ~ data$Cuatro_Caminos')
                   )

lapply(formula_list, FUN = lm, data = data)
```

Data

```
data <- structure(list(date = structure(c(14610, 14611, 14612, 14613, 
14614, 14615, 14616, 14617, 14618, 14619), class = "Date"), Moratalaz = c(35, 
62, 76, 69, 67, 48, 37, 39, 47, 66), Cuatro_Caminos = c(19, 40, 
65, 64, 52, 33, 50, 37, 33, 51), Barrio_de_Pilar = c(23, 40, 
53, 52, 40, 29, 28, 19, 31, 41), Vallecas = c(21, 44, 55, 56, 
54, 37, 28, 26, 33, 47)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using

```
combn(names(data)[-1], 2, FUN = function(x)
 lm(reformulate(x[1], response = x[2]), data = data), simplify = FALSE)
```

Comment: I get the following error `Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
  se intenta usar un nombre de varible de longitud cero` It trying to use a variable name of length zero.

Comment: @user113156 it didnt give me the error though.  But, I think your question is to get all pairwise lm.  which i updated

Comment: Okay, the error occurs on the full sample of the data.

Comment: One additional question, how can I set the list names to the different combinations of column names? The code generates the formulas and i'm just thinking if I can name the list names to the formulas.